# How 10.0.2.2 of emulator resolves to 127.0.0.1 of windows?

Tags: android, localhost

We use 10.0.2.2 as the localhost address for emulators in our Android apps. How can a service running on windows(127.0.0.1) resolves to the emulator's 10.0.2.2?

Why is 10.0.2.2 equivalent to localhost in Android?

Comment: It is a special address interpreted directly by the emulator http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses

Comment: @etienne Is there any interlink among the two addresses? How they are interlinked?

Comment: I don't get the question; what do you try to achieve?

Comment: @etienne My service is running on 127.0.0.1, how that communicates with emulator's 10.0.2.2(localhost for emulator)?

Comment: When your application accesses 10.0.2.2, the emulator intercepts this address and translates it as 127.0.0.1 on the machine it runs onto.

Comment: the interesting case is that 127.0.0.1 is using default port of 80.
when the developers came with a different port, they may got some troubles. I dunno how to solve that anyway.